# How to make only one card out of a grid of cards expand at a time?

Tags: reactjs, expand, framer-motion, card

I have a grid of 'cards' displaying games that when clicked expand down to show more information however when I click on one ALL of the cards expand open and I'm wanting only one to expand at a time.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/game-cards-i9vxcl) of what I have so far. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working component. The component state must reflect currently open card or null if no card is open.
Also changed `class` to `className` since it's the proper way to set component class from CSS

```
export const GameCard = () => {

  const [openedCard, setOpenedCard] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div id="card_wrapper">
      {games.map((game) => (
        <motion.div
          transition={{ layout: { duration: 1, type: "spring" } }}
          layout
          onClick={() => setOpenedCard(game.id)}
          key={game.id}
          className="card"
          name={game.name}
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${game.background})`,
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
          }}
        >
          <motion.h2 layout="position">
            {" "}
            <img src={game.logo} alt={game.alt} />
          </motion.h2>
          {openedCard === game.id && (
            <motion.div
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
              transition={{ duration: 1 }}
              className="expand"
            >
              <p> {game.description} </p>
            </motion.div>
          )}
        </motion.div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The issue of expanding all cards when any is clicked had nothing to do with React but it's caused by `#card_wrapper` flex-box settings: `align-items` is by default set to `stretch` but you need it to be `flex-start` instead.

```
#card_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

BTW. You had `#card_wrapper` defined twice in your stylesheet - made one instead.

And the last but least - remember to use `className` prop instead of `class` - you need to fix `games.js` for that issue.

Comment: Unfortunately all of the cards still expand with this but only the selected cards description shows

Comment: well, I've shown you the way to make the component opening one card at the time and by opening I mean conditional rendering `motion.div` section for clicked card. I don't know how the layout should look when the card is closed - only the title? title with some background? There are no actual class definitions in provided `styles.css`...

Comment: I'm actually passing the game card component into a games screen. I updated the codesandbox to reflect that. #games_container div on the games screen is set to display: flex

Comment: Hm for some reason the changes wouldn't save, I recreated and updated the link to the sandbox that should have all the updated code

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
// add new state to capture the index of the clicked element :
const [elementId, setElementId] = useState(null);
```

and in the return part capture the clicked index inside the onClick :

```
return (
    <div id="card_wrapper">
      {games.map((game) => (
        <motion.div
          transition={{ layout: { duration: 1, type: "spring" } }}
          layout
          onClick={() => {
            setIsOpen(!isOpen);
            setElementId(game.id);
       }}
...)
```

and finally render motion only when (isOpen) and (game.id === elementId) :

```
{isOpen && game.id === elementId && (
            <motion.div
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
              transition={{ duration: 1 }}
              class="expand"
            >
```

full sandbox example : [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-dawn-6jt0g3?file=/src/components/gameCard.js:6749-6977)

Comment: hint: update the import of the GameCard component with `{ GameCard }` in the App.js because it is not a default export there ;) (throws an error)

Comment: thanks for the hint, it was and still curently `import { GameCard } from "./components/gameCard";` maybe sanbox is not updating :(

Comment: You can use just one state variable - id of opened game card or null if all cards are closed.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @dink74 .. just updated the initial state :)

Comment: This works if the cards aren't in a line (I used flexbox row) so when they're in a row they still all expand they just don't all show descriptions

Comment: @MaycieMorris this will show the description of the clicked element regardless its `CSS` properties :)

Comment: @MaycieMorris where are you adding the `flexbox row`? is it the `className="card"`? can you please share a sandbox of what you are trying achieve with `CSS`

Comment: I'm actually passing the game card component into a games screen. I updated the codesandbox to reflect that. #games_container div on the games screen is set to display: flex

Comment: @OmarDieh - I fixed the "expanding cards issue" which was the CSS problem, not the React itself.